# Partitions of $n$ into even number of parts versus into odd number of parts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I'm under the impression that if $n$ is even then the number of partitions of $n$ into an even number of parts exceeds the number of partitions of $n$ into an odd number of parts. And the opposite if $n$ is odd.

I feel like this is clear by looking at small examples, but I can't give a rigorous proof. I think it follows from how you make the partitions out of $n$ ones.

Would anyone be able to help me gain some more intuition about this or provide me with a proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct for $n>2$.

If $n>2$, $n$ has at least one self-conjugate partition; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015509/for-each-integer-n-2-determine-a-self-conjugate-partition-of-n-that-has-at). If $c(n)$ is the number of self-conjugate partitions of $n$, $$c(n)=(-1)^n(p_E(n)-p_O(n))\,,$$ where $p_E(n)$ and $p_O(n)$ are the numbers of partitions of $n$ with an even and an odd number of parts, respectively; this is proved in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92191/identity-involving-partitions-of-even-and-odd-parts). Thus, $c(n)$ is positive for $n>2$, so $p_E(n)-p_O(n)$ must be positive for even $n>2$ and negative for odd $n>2$.